# Excel 2013 VBA Disable Escape Key

Tags: vba, excel

Huge apologies. Have looked for this answer for hours and cannot find it.

I've tried various ways to disable my escape key in a worksheet.

All to no avail. I've joined the community with a view to asking for some help please.

I've tried

```
Application.EnableCancelKey = xLDisabled
```

And I've used

```
Application.OnKey "{ESC}", ""
```

I don't want the escape key turned off in the entire workbook just the worksheet I am in.

I'd welcome some help please.

I'm not a prolific VBA writer - it's more that I do it for work than a living.

Thank you

Nutty

Comment: Cancel Key pertains to VBA code execution, and both that and `OnKey` is an application-level setting so either approach you've tried so far will affect *every* workbook, even after you close the current workbook.  What specific behavior are you actually trying to prevent (and why)? I ask because there may be other/better options available.

Comment: sorry if i am missing a Point, but why you don't assign a function to your application.onkey {"Esc"} Event, and check the activeWorksheet.Name ?

Comment: David, I would like to prevent users from changing the full screen setting. So I've been working out a routine that will set the screen size and disable the non essential stuff in a worksheet and provide my own navigation.#

Answer (score 1):

Are you searching for something like this?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet2"  Then
     Application.OnKey "{ESC}", ""
  Else
     Application.OnKey "{ESC}"
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
   If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet2"  Then
       Application.OnKey "{ESC}", ""
   Else
       Application.OnKey "{ESC}"
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
   Application.OnKey "{ESC}"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   Application.OnKey "{ESC}"
End Sub
```

Comment: I think I am yes. Thank you. May I ask. I think I may have confused myself a little. The ribbon is the only element that is reappearing when I hit the escape key. I suspect I haven't understood that I need to disable the ribbon too?