# VBA- Cannot disable cancel key

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot seem to get this function working, would someone mind reviewing my code and letting me know what I'm doing wrong?

Basically what I'm trying to do is disable the escape key to break the macro from start to finish. I want it to continue through uninterrupted (I am not concerned about loops).

See below for my full code.

````
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
        
    Dim UserName As String
    UserName = Environ$("UserName")
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Dim ThisBook
    ThisBook = ThisWorkbook.Name

    ' Job Variables from Excel
    
    Dim vCRQ As String
    vCRQ = Workbooks(ThisBook).Worksheets("Variables").Range("B6")
    Dim vLogical As String
    vLogical = Workbooks(ThisBook).Worksheets("Variables").Range("B7")
    Dim vBobRef As String
    vBobRef = Workbooks(ThisBook).Worksheets("Variables").Range("B8")
    Dim vOldFileName
    vOldFileName = Workbooks(ThisBook).Worksheets("Variables").Range("B9")
    Dim vNewFileName
    vNewFileName = Workbooks(ThisBook).Worksheets("Variables").Range("B10")
    Dim vValid
    vValid = Workbooks(ThisBook).Worksheets("Helper").Range("D15")
    
    If vValid = "No" Then
        
    Call sndPlaySound32 _
    ("C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify System Generic.wav", 0)
    
    MsgBox "CRQ is not valid today!"
    
    
    Else

    
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim BobStartTime As String

    'Remember time when macro starts
    StartTime = Timer
    
    BobStartTime = Format((StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
    
    Application.StatusBar = "Bob Checks Commenced at " & BobStartTime
    
    ' Start Bot
    
    Dim bot As WebDriver
    Set bot = New ChromeDriver

    bot.Get "website.com"
    DoEvents

    ' Login Page
 
    Do Until i = 1
        If bot.FindElementsById("idp-discovery-username").Count() > 0 Then
            bot.FindElementById("idp-discovery-username").SendKeys UserName
            bot.FindElementsById("idp-discovery-submit").Item(1).Click
            bot.Wait 500
            i = 1
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    i = 0
    
    ' Type "mis"
    Do Until i = 1
        If bot.FindElementsById("menu-search-input").Count() > 0 Then
            bot.FindElementById("menu-search-input").SendKeys "mis"
            bot.Wait 500
            i = 1
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    i = 0
    
    ' Click "Display DSLAM Port Mismatch"
    Do Until i = 1
        If bot.FindElementsByXPath("//span[text()='Display DSLAM Port Mismatch']").Count() > 0 Then
            bot.FindElementsByXPath("//span[text()='Display DSLAM Port Mismatch']").Item(1).Click
            bot.Wait 1000
            i = 1
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    i = 0
    
    ' Type "DSLAM ID"
    Do Until i = 1
        If bot.FindElementsById("prompt0").Count() > 0 Then
            bot.Wait 500
            bot.FindElementById("prompt0").SendKeys vLogical
            bot.Wait 500
            i = 1
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    i = 0

    ' Type "Bob Ref"
    Do Until i = 1
        If bot.FindElementsById("prompt1").Count() > 0 Then
            bot.FindElementById("prompt1").SendKeys vBobRef
            bot.Wait 500
            i = 1
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    i = 0

    ' Click Continue
 
    Do Until i = 1
        If bot.FindElementsById("button").Count() > 0 Then
            bot.FindElementsById("button").Item(1).Click
            bot.Wait 500
            i = 1
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    i = 0
    
     
    ' If Precheck... Continue Again
    
    If Workbooks(ThisBook).Worksheets("Variables").Range("B5") = "Precheck" Then
    
    For i = 1 To 10
        If bot.FindElementsById("button").Count() > 0 Then
            bot.Wait 500
            bot.FindElementsById("button").Item(1).Click
            bot.Wait 1000
            i = 1
        End If
        DoEvents
    Next i
    
    End If
    
    i = 0
    
        
    ' If Postcheck...
    If Workbooks(ThisBook).Worksheets("Variables").Range("B5") = "Postcheck" Then
    
        Call sndPlaySound32 _
        ("C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify System Generic.wav", 0)
        MsgBox "Select Precheck to Compare, Continue then OK"
    
        If bot.FindElementsById("button").Count() > 0 Then
        bot.FindElementsById("button").Item(1).Click
        End If
        DoEvents
        
    End If
    
    i = 0

    ' Click "Full DSLAM Report download CSV"
    Do Until i = 1
        If bot.FindElementsByXPath("//*[text()='Full DSLAM Report download CSV']").Count() > 0 Then
            bot.FindElementsByXPath("//*[text()='Full DSLAM Report download CSV']").Item(1).Click
            bot.Wait 500
            i = 1
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    i = 0
    
    bot.Wait 5000
    
    Name vOldFileName As vNewFileName
    
    
    
    Call sndPlaySound32 _
    ("C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav", 0)
    
    Application.StatusBar = False
    
    Worksheets("Helper").RunBob.BackColor = RGB(51, 153, 102)

    
    End If
        
  
    
End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0):

Another user had posted that the application.enableCan is not working.

[Excel 2013 VBA Disable Escape Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985762/excel-2013-vba-disable-escape-key)

Their solution is to use an OnKey event  , where it's capturing the ESC key and substituting it with a null- appear to be the preferred way.

```
Application.OnKey "{ESC}",""
```

Just be careful to re-enable it again!